# Implementing Facebook into Xcode Project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, facebook, github

I am going to be implementing the facebook application into my project, but I've ran into some roadblocks. First I read about the link that developers.facebook.com has posted:
[image]

I really don't know how to use the GitHub repository and add it to my app project, so I hope I can get some help with that,

Next, while I was continuing the rest, I found something that I might need help on as well:
[image]

So that's all I have for now, I just need to get through this first part, then I can continue on, so I hope someone can help me get on through that first part, thanks

(sorry if I had to post the pictures, I just really need to be specific and I'm sometimes having trouble with reading tutorials)

Comment: It would be useful if you link to the source of the screenshot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not familiar with git you can download the sdk manually to your hard drive on this page: `https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk` click on downloads and select the preferred format.

On the readme clearly states how to add the library to your own application:

> If you want to integrate Facebook with an existing application, then follow these steps:
>
> - Copy the Facebook SDK into your Xcode project:
>
>   - In Xcode, open the Facebook SDK by selecting *File*->*Open...* and selecting src/facebook-ios-sdk.xcodeproj.
>   - With your own application project open in Xcode, drag and drop the "FBConnect" folder from the Facebook SDK project into your application's project.
>   - Include the FBConnect headers in your code:
>
>     `#import "FBConnect/FBConnect.h"`
>   - You should now be able to compile your project successfully.
> - Register your application with Facebook:
>
>   - Create a new Facebook application at: http://www.facebook.com/developers/createapp.php. If you already have a related web application, you can use the same application ID.
>   - Set your application's name and picture. This is what users will see when they authorize your application.

You should have a file called `yourProjectNameAppDelegate.h` and `yourProjectNameAppDelegate.m`.

You have to put `#import "FBConnect/FBConnect.h"` into `yourProjectNameAppDelegate.h`.
And declare a variable in the header `Facebook* facebok;` and also synthesize it.

Your `yourProjectNameAppDelegate.m` contains a method called `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` which should look like:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
   facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"YOUR_APP_ID"];
   [facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];

}
```

Also put in this file the other method.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url{
    return [facebook handleOpenUrl:url];
}
```

Also I suggest to learn a bit more about objective-c, because your problems are not related to the facebook library. You can find plenty of resources on the net. I suggest to look this iTunes university [screencast](http://itunes.apple.com/itunes-u/iphone-application-development/id384233225).

Comment: hey thanks alot for your help, I copied the FBConnect folder into my project, then I inserted the #import "FBConnect/FBConnect.h" into my appdelegate file, but when I compile it says no such file or directory, when I remove the "FBConnect/" and said #import "FBConnect.h" it ran great, I was wondering if this is what you ment? Also, I am doing this project based on a Tab Bar Application, so I was wondering if it's ok to put the facebook imports on a another header file rather than the delegate files, so that when I click a Tab, it will open my facebook application right away? Thanks again!

Comment: The import works like that probably because the `FBConnect.h` is in your app root and not in the `FBConnect/`. You can import the header anywhere you want to use it, it was imported into the `AppDelegate` because  it was used there.

Answer (score 1):

for github, go to http://help.github.com/ they have loads of resources to help you out, but you pretty much just need to type git clone , and then find where it has put the repository.

alternatively if you browse to the repo on the github website, you should be able to just click a download button.

with the second bit, what do you need help with?

the app id will be from when you have set your application up in facebook.

Comment: Hey thanks alot for your help too, first of all, I am creating my project based on a Tab Bar application and on my third Tab Bar Item, I have a couple of buttons that launches like Facebook, Twitter, Myspace and all those sort of social network applications. Now for the second part, I didn't create the #import FBConnect.h into my delegate file because I have another file called FacebookPage.h and .m, so I created it there and I dont see the pplication:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions so is there a way to implement this whole thing into a Tab Bar Application? Thanks!

Comment: is the FacebookPage class a subclass of UIViewController?

Comment: yes, its a subclass of UIViewController, so how can I get this working with a Tab Bar Controller? Thanks

Comment: I've set up the tabs and buttons in IB, and the linking the rest in code